# QGIS: JSON Load error: Invallid Layer cannot be loaded in: Origin is GeoJSON

Tags: qgis-3, geojson, api

So far I have tried to load in a GeoJSON inside QGIS, but I get a problem doing so.

To give some context I am testing a system, where we can get a JSON more specifcally a GeoJson from a API. for now we are testing it with the public API. Link to the Public API documentation is here:
http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/#!index.md

Edit 2:

Okay after some digging I have found out that this JSON file..while clearly being established to geojson format, **it is not format that is recognized by QGIS, if anyone can tell me why the heck this is feel free to do so. When clearly it has been established to be Geojson on the website. So what is going on here?**

**For now I am just testing if I can load the JSON file inside QGIS, since the public API claims the JSON file it delivers is in GEOJSON format. How we are gonna format that data is another step.**

http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/#!docs/technical.md

Now for getting the JSON file itself I use this link:
http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment

And just save the file as JSON file.

Is my method wrong, or is there something else going on?

I am using QGIS 3.4.5 for now but later versions also have the same problem.

What I am doing wrong here? Is it method of delivering the JSON file itself? Or is there something else going on?

Here is the demo page they made:
https://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/Demo/workassignment.html

**Also of note I currently use the QGIS 3.4.5 version for the JSON file load.**

Edit: This is the file you get:

```
[
  {
    "gipodId": 464424,
    "owner": "PIDPA drinkwater",
    "description": "2400 MOL - Gompelbaan",
    "startDateTime": "2014-02-13T08:00:00",
    "endDateTime": "2021-05-30T17:00:00",
    "importantHindrance": false,
    "coordinate": {
      "coordinates": [
        5.154672992272043,
        51.1939327342695
      ],
      "type": "Point",
      "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
      }
    },
    "detail": "http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment/464424?crs=WGS84",
    "cities": [
      "Mol"
    ],
    "latestUpdate": "2020-11-09T18:30:36.767"
  },
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: I cannot load in the JSON file (it is a GEOJSON). QGIS keeps saying it is a invallid layer. While it should not be, it clearly is a GeoJSON file. I can directly save the JSON by save as.

Comment: and does it work when you save the file locally? please show us some of the file

Comment: What do you mean when I save locally when I clearly already saved it locally by save as? I have given you on one record looks specifically.